# Swift: retrieving text from a UITextField in a custom UITableViewCell and putting it in an array

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm making a very simple app where the user enters the number of people in the first Screen.

In the second screen it generates a number of `UITableViewCell` based on the number the user entered in the first screen. The `UITableViewCell` have a `UITextField` in them and I'm trying to store the data entered in those fields in an array once the user clicks to go to the third screen.

How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance!

### Edit: I'm using the storyboard.

Here is what the code that calls for the custom `UITableViewCell` looks like for my `UIViewController`:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        
    var cell: EditingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as EditingCell
    
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }
    
    let person = arrayOfPeople[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.setCell(person.name)
    
            
    return cell
}
```

Here is what the code for the `UITableViewCell` looks like:

```
class EditingCell: UITableViewCell{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameInput: UITextField!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    
    func setCell(name:String){
        self.nameInput.placeholder = name
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give us something to go on:  Add any relevant code to your post.  Are you working in Swift or Objective-C?  Purely in code, or using a storyboard?  How far have you got?  What's not working?  Do you get a specific error?  Thanks.

Comment: @pbasdf Is it more clear now? Nothing is not working. I just have no clue how to be able to get the data from the UITextfield from the class EditingCell

Comment: Much, thanks.  Do you want your array to contain the `nameInput` text for all the cells, or just the one selected?  I assume the next view controller is loaded by "clicking" a cell - or is there a separate button?

Comment: Yes, I want the text for all the cells to be placed in the array in order. and the next view controller is loaded by clicking a button.

Comment: OK.  It's kind of late here now - I'll take a look tomorrow.  But to help get you started: you will want to loop through all rows, build the indexPath for each row (use NSIndexPath(forRow: inSection:)) and then use tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the associated cell.  Then you can access cell.nameInput.text and add it to your array.

Comment: @vidalbenjoe this question was asked two years before the question you are referencing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a problem with your approach if the number of rows in your table exceeds the number that can fit on screen.  In that case, the cells that scroll off-screen will be re-used, and the contents of the `nameInput` textField will be lost.  If you can be sure that this will never happen, use the following code (in the method that handles button taps) to compose your array:

```
        var arrayOfNames : [String] = [String]()
        for var i = 0; i<self.arrayOfPeople.count; i++ {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:i, inSection:0)
            let cell : EditingCell? = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as EditingCell?
            if let item = cell?.nameInput.text {
                arrayOfNames.append(item)
            }
        }
        println("\(arrayOfNames)")
```

**Alternatively....**

However, if it is possible that cells will scroll off-screen, I suggest a different solution.  Set the `delegate` for the `nameInput` text fields, and then use the delegate methods to grab the names as they are entered.

First, add variables to your view controller, to hold the array and the row number of the text field currently being edited.

```
    var arrayOfNames : [String] = [String]()
    var rowBeingEdited : Int? = nil
```

Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, add:

```
    cell.nameInput.text = "" // just in case cells are re-used, this clears the old value
    cell.nameInput.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.nameInput.delegate = self
```

Then add two new functions, to catch when the text fields begin/end editing:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let row = textField.tag
    if row >= arrayOfNames.count {
        for var addRow = arrayOfNames.count; addRow <= row; addRow++ {
            arrayOfNames.append("") // this adds blank rows in case the user skips rows
        }
    }
    arrayOfNames[row] = textField.text
    rowBeingEdited = nil
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    rowBeingEdited = textField.tag
}
```

When the user taps the button, they might still be editing one of the names.  To cater for this, add the following to the method that handles the button taps:

```
        if let row = rowBeingEdited {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row, inSection:0)
            let cell : EditingTableViewCell? = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as EditingTableViewCell?
            cell?.nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
```

This forces the textField to complete editing, and hence trigger the `didEndEditing` method, thereby saving the text to the array.

Comment: That works fine if you don't have sections in your table, but how would you implement it with sections?

Comment: Mind help me with that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125286/getting-the-value-textfield-from-form-based-uitableview.The textfield really work!!But,I need help with button again.

Comment: Can anyone provide this in Swift 3?

Comment: This answer should not even mention the option of getting the data from all of the cells.

Comment: How can I handle the same scenario when I have check and uncheck images?

Answer (score 0):

Here for new swift versions of answer

```
    var arrayOfNames : [String] = [String]()
    var i = 0
    while i < taskArrForRead.count {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        let cell : taslakDuzenlemeCell? = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! taslakDuzenlemeCell?
        if let item = cell?.taslakTextField.text {
            arrayOfNames.append(item)
        }
        i = i + 1
    }
    print("\(arrayOfNames)")
```