# Getting the value textfield from Form based UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I got UITableView with one custom cell which will show the question data from server response json,So,I got 1 UILabel,3 UIButtons (Which will be radio button) and 1 UITextField which I declare like that.

[image]

The below textfield at each table cell is remark and the radio button (Yes,No,N/A) are just UIButtons.

These are survey questions as you can see,set that at UITableView.

If there are 21 Questions response from server,I will show 21 rows which show question title,selection buttons,and remark on each tablecell.

So,What is my problem,I really don't know how to get the data from each table cell when user click submit button.

When i submit,i want to get the data like that : 
[[String:String],[String:String],...]

Example : Assume I do survey on 1st and 2nd table cell,I want to get the data like that.You will see the 3rd one is empty data if the user didn't fill.

```
[
     ["QuestionID": 1,"Type":"Yes","Remark":"Nothing special everything good"],
     ["QuestionID": 2,"Type":"No","Remark":"Yeah,it will be alot helpful"],
     ["QuestionID": 3,"Type":"","Remark":""]
]
```

Any Help?Please?How to get the data and save like that even the user didnt fill when we submit the survey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can identify the particular `UITextField` or `UIButton` by getting the `NSIndexPath`. You just need to `addTarget` and get the current `NSIndexPath` and from there you can get the current clicked `UITableViewCell`.

First `addTarget` to the `UITextField` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.textFieldSearch.addTarget(self, action: "textChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

Then you can handle the click event in the below function:

```
func textChange(textField: UITextField){

    var cellIndexPath = tableViewSearch.indexPathForCell(textField.superview!.superview! as! UITableViewCell)!
    let cell = tableViewSearch.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndexPath!) as! SearchRatingCell
    cell.textFieldSearch.text = textField.text!   
}
```

> Update (`UIButton`):

```
cell.yesButton.addTarget(self, action: "searchByRating:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Custom Method:

```
func searchByRating(sender: UIButton){

    let cellIndexPath = tableViewSearch.indexPathForCell(sender.superview!.superview! as! SearchRatingCell)!
    let cell = tableViewSearch.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndexPath!) as! SearchRatingCell
    cell.yesButton.selected = true
}
```

Let me know, if you have any confusion.

Comment: For `UIButton` also, you can do the same thing. Just apply the target and make your own custom method. @6245Htarwara

Comment: @6245Htarwara Check the edited answer!

Comment: Mind share me with example?I still don't know how to get the data from textfield of specific uitableviewcell where user type.I am completely lost at there.Please help

Comment: @6245Htarwara Let me check and go through it!

Comment: @6245Htarwara Or can you please send me the demo project so that I can edit and send you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106897/discussion-between-6245htarwara-and-sohil-r-memon).

Comment: You look really good at logically programming,mind help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441532/creating-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-base-on-response-json

Comment: @6245Htarwara Ok Let me check

Comment: Sounds,really complex right?You are welcome to join there.PagingMenuController is just an example,you can use other library too.

Comment: @6245Htarwara Yes, really complex one!