# Creating UIViewController programmatically base on response json

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

Assume my json will be

```
{
      {"CategoryID" : "1 Month Premium"},
      {"CategoryID" : "1 Year Premium"},
      {"CategoryID" : "1 Week Premium"},
      {"CategoryID" : "1 Day Premium"},
      ....Dynamically created server data.
}
```

And I gonna use PagingMenuController from this library : [PagingMenuController](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController)

Base on the JSON which I described above, **Category** will be different,they may be 4 or 5,or more or less.So,Its dynamic.

This is how I gonna develope

[image]

As you can see,I will display CategoryID on PagingMenu.All the viewcontroller inside each page menu have common items :

**UITableView,UIImageView,UIButton**

So,how do i create UIViewController which have common items and actions on each view and insert to my page controller.I really need help with that.I don't know how to do it programatically.It was more like google play store app which page menu are created dynamically.

Any Help?Please,all my life,I used only storyboard and view controller.From now,I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following tutorial.  It is in objective-c but it will help you to understand the logic.

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: Umm,I am just beginner to swift..dont know any objective-C syntax,sorry.;(

Comment: @Aditya Shinde, Do not post links to other blogs/websites. Explain as much as you can about it and then for further reference add links.