# UITextField in customed TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, nsmutablearray

I have an `UITextField` object in customed `UITableViewCell` and a `NSMutablearray` (choicesArray), like following codes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];


  self.choicesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
  [self.choicesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"]];
  [self.choicesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.choicesArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AddChoiceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"choiceCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *string = [self.choicesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.choiceTextField.text = string;

    return cell;
}
```

When I enter other text of `UITextField` , I want to change object of choices array.

What can I do?

Comment: it is very bad idea to put textfield in **UITableview** because when you scroll cell will reuse every time and possibly data lost on textfield

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27743391/3985749) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textField` delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing` and in this method you can update your array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the UITextField has a connection to delegate and datasource
2. Use the UITextField delegate such as TextFieldDidBeginEditing and TextFieldDidEndEditing