# Save tableview textfields to an array of custom objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, swift2

I´m searching for a way to save the data a user enters in two textfields in a tableview. The user has to enter the name and the height of person in a tableview and I want to save it to a custom array.

```
struct PersonData {
    var name: String
    var height: Int

    init(name: String, height: Int) {
        self.name = name        
        self.height = height
    }
}
```

I´ve searched and i found this [Swift: retrieving text from a UITextField in a custom UITableViewCell and putting it in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726769/swift-retrieving-text-from-a-uitextfield-in-a-custom-uitableviewcell-and-puttin) but still got two questions.

How i add item to my custom array? I try it with this:

```
personData[textField.tag].name = textField.text!
```

Isn´t a easier way to do it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly then heres a possible solution.

You initialise an array of type PersonData. Then you make an object of type PersonData. Whenever you have some info, you store it in this object and append the object to the array created.

```
 let array = [PersonData]()
    let personDataObject = PersonData()

    //After you store the values in the object you add the object to you array.
   personDataObject.name = textField1.text
   personDataObject.height = textField2.text //You need to convert this to Int. Try personDataObject.height = textField2.text as? Int or personDataObject.height = Int(textField2.text)

     array.append(personDataObject)
```

Comment: Yes i thought that but the point is i have to fill the array every time the user ends editing a textfield so that answer is impossible to me :(

Comment: When user ends editing, give a button that says Finish or Submit and then clear the textfields. He will be able to enter new data and the same process will repeat. Could you try this?

Comment: Didn´t thought that i´m going to try that way