# Textfield gets empty when tableview is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview and a separate xib for custom cells in which i have multiple labels and a textfield.

I want to get entered values from all the cells on the button click but using `for cell in self.tableViewList.visibleCells {` gives me the values of only visible cells and all other textfield values are lost.

Please suggest me some alternative to get all the textfield values.

i'm using swift 3 and developing an ipad application.

Comment: Share you relevant code

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27743391/3901620v

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the reuse of UITableViewCells.
The cell class from your xib is not created for each of your data item (row).
It is reused while scrolling, which means same instance of UITableViewCell can display multiple instances of data.

The solution is too keep data in "dataSource" - outside of tableView and apply the values to the cells on "cellForRow" method.
On UITextField changes, you have to modify values inside dataSource (for example by using delegate pattern).