# Reading data from TV

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I'm trying to read data from a table view,I've created the following method:

```
/**
 Salva le nuove info dell'Evento modificato
*/
private func SalvaEventoModificato(){

    self.Effetto_blur.alpha = 1

    var IndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    //let nome_Evento = ((self.table_viewCosaVisualizzare.cellForRow(at: IndexPath as IndexPath)) as! cella_locale_modifica).NomeEvento.text!

    var nome_evento = ""
    var artista = ""
    var genere = ""
    var descrizione = ""
    var data_inizio:NSNumber? = nil
    var data_fine:NSNumber? = nil
    var Immagine_Evento:UIImage? = nil


    if let cell = ((self.table_viewCosaVisualizzare.cellForRow(at: IndexPath as IndexPath)) as? cella_locale_modifica){
        nome_evento = cell.NomeEvento.text!
        Immagine_Evento = cell.CopertinaLocale.image!
    }

    IndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)

    if let cella2 = ((self.table_viewCosaVisualizzare.cellForRow(at: IndexPath as IndexPath)) as? g_cella){

        artista = cella2.Artista.text!
        genere = cella2.Genere.text!

    }

    IndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)

    if let cella3 = ((self.table_viewCosaVisualizzare.cellForRow(at: IndexPath as IndexPath)) as? descrizione_cella){
         descrizione = cella3.descrizione.text
    }

    IndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 8, section: 0)


    if let cella4 = ((self.table_viewCosaVisualizzare.cellForRow(at: IndexPath as IndexPath)) as? inizio_evento_cella){

        data_inizio = cella4.data_picker.date.timeIntervalSince1970 as NSNumber
    }

    IndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 12, section: 0)

    if let cella5 = ((self.table_viewCosaVisualizzare.cellForRow(at: IndexPath as IndexPath)) as? inizio_evento_cella){

        data_fine = cella5.data_picker.date.timeIntervalSince1970 as NSNumber
    }


    let nuoviDati:[String:Any] = ["Nome Evento":nome_evento,"Artista":artista,"Genere":genere,"Descrizione":descrizione,"Inizio Evento":data_inizio!,"Fine Evento":data_fine]



    let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("Eventi").child(self.EventoCorrente.Chiave!).child("Copertina").child("Copertina.jpg")

    IndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)


    if let dati = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Immagine_Evento!, 0.6){
        print("salvo nuova copertina")

        storage.putData(dati, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, Error) in

            if Error != nil{

                let avviso = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Si è verificato un Errore con la modifica del tuo Evento, riprova più tardi.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                let Ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

                    self.Effetto_blur.alpha = 0

                    return

                })

                avviso.addAction(Ok)

                self.present(avviso, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }else{

                if let RemotePhoto = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                    let url_copertina = RemotePhoto

                    let nuoviDati:[String:Any] = ["Nome Evento":nome_evento,"Artista":artista,"Genere":genere,"Descrizione":descrizione,"Immagine Copertina":url_copertina,"Inizio Evento":data_inizio!,"Fine Evento":data_fine!]

                    self.ref.child("Eventi").child(self.EventoCorrente.Chiave!).updateChildValues(nuoviDati)

                    self.Effetto_blur.alpha = 0

                }
            }

        })

    }

}
```

that works fine but it seems to read only the cell that are loaded in the current view of the user , for example:

[image]

output the following:

```
["Descrizione": "Benvenuto nella pagina dell\'Evento di debug", "Genere": "Debug", "Artista": "Debug", "Fine Evento": nil, "Inizio Evento": 1495058400, "Nome Evento": "Evento Dubig"]
Optional(<UIImage: 0x6000002914e0> size {1000, 1000} orientation 0 scale 1.000000)
```

instead this :

[image]

Output this:

```
["Descrizione": "Benvenuto nella pagina dell\'Evento di debug", "Genere": "", "Artista": "", "Fine Evento": Optional(1523764800), "Inizio Evento": 1495058400, "Nome Evento": ""]
nil
```

is there a way to read from ***ALL*** the cells?

Comment: Your table is a *view* on your data, it is not your data. You should get the data from the data source, not from the cells. Cells that are not currently on screen don't exist.

Comment: yeah I know, but this table view let the user change some data the than simply display them so i need to read the changes from the table view

Comment: @GiulioSerra See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27743391/3985749) to a similar question.

Comment: No, you need to capture those changes when they are made and update your data model. As soon as the tableview scrolls those changes are going to be lost; when the cell scrolls back into view the tableview will call `cellForRowAt` which will refer to your data model to provide the cell.