# UITableViewCell tag changes after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am creating a form in `UITableView`. This form has a `UILabel` and `UITextField` in a prototype cell. Each `UITextField` has a unique tag.
When user clicks submit button, I want to get value from each `UITextField` using a tag.
Now the problem is I have 18 `UITextField` and when I enter values in the field and scroll the view to fill the remaining fields, after filling the data when I press submit button, the app crashes. It won't be able to find the tag of first `UITextField`.

I want to compare UITextFields value. But I don't want to collect all textfields value. I want to retrieve particular textfield value and compare it with other textfield value on the submit button click.

[This is how my UITableView Looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo2vU.png)

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SurveyFormTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SurveyFormTableViewCell

    var  pest_code = textfield_id_value[indexPath.row].pest_code
    var srno = textfield_id_value[indexPath.row].srno
    var inspection_no = textfield_id_value[indexPath.row].inspection_no

    cell.text_field.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    cell.text_field.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.text_field.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(tableFieldDidChange(_textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
    let id:Int = Int("\(srno)\(pest_code)\(inspection_no)")!
    cell.text_field.tag = id

    cell.label?.text =  struc_array[indexPath.item].pest
    cell.label?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.label?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

    return cell
}

@IBAction func submit_survey_clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    text_field =  self.table_view.viewWithTag(textfield_tag1) as! UITextField
    text_field2 =  self.table_view.viewWithTag(textfield_tag2) as! UITextField
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27743391/3985749) to a similar question might be of use.

Comment: I don't want to collect all textfields value. I want to retrieve particular textfield value and compare it with other textfield value.Suppose i want to retrieve fourth row textfield value and compare it with third row textfield value then how will I achieve this ?

Comment: The point is that you MUST collect all the textFields' values, before they are scrolled off screen.  Otherwise the cell will be re-used, the tag will be changed, and you will not be able to recover the textField value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to work for a couple of reasons:

1) The table view cells are reused.  So you get the cell for the first item and assign it say tag 1 but then as you scroll that cell gets reused for say cell 15 (just an example) and you assign the tag the number 15.  Now the SAME textfield that had the tag 1 has the tag 15.

2) You are looking on your table view for a view with the text field tag but the text field is not a sub view of the table view it belongs to the cell instead so it will never be found.

EDIT

This is a very basic example of using a data model [Basic Data Model Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/in64d4f20zxl3o4/Test_DataModel.zip?dl=0)

(Note: this won't stay available for ever I may delete it in a week or so)

(Also Note: this is a very basic example and not in anyway the most complete method with proper validation, etc).

**EDIT**

If you want to make a list of the values that have been entered for each unique entry in your data list you can use a dictionary.  This is an example based on the details you have supplied in the comments:

First change the textfieldId struct so that it adopts the Hashable protocol and can therefore be used as the key in your dictionary like this:

```
struct textfieldId: Hashable {
    var srno:Int
    var pest_code:Int
    var inspection_no:Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        return srno.hashValue ^ pest_code.hashValue ^ inspection_no.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: textfieldId, rhs: textfieldId) -> Bool {
        return lhs.srno == rhs.srno && lhs.pest_code == rhs.pest_code && lhs.inspection_no == rhs.inspection_no
    }
}
```

Then define a dictionary to hold the details that have been entered for each of the data items like this:

```
var enteredValues: [textfieldId: String] = [:]
```

Now whenever the text entered changes you store it in the dictionary like this:

```
self.enteredValues[id] = textEntered // Update for your project
```

and to get the information back again (for example to update the cell) do this:

```
cell.textField.text = self.enteredValues[id] // Update for your project.
```

Doing this you have created a dictionary of the values that have been entered that is unique to each data item.

If you need to clear the list you can do this:

```
self.enteredValues.removeAll()
```

or create a new instance like this:

```
self.enteredValues = [:]
```

Comment: So, what should I do now ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  What should happen when you tap the submit button?

Comment: I want to get value from  textfield.

Comment: Is there a single submit button or is it one per cell? and Do you want to get the value of the textfield in just one cell or all of them?

Comment: No, there is only one submit button.

Comment: Sorry I updated the comment so you might have missed the second bit.  Is it just the value of one cells text field you want or all of them?  If it's just one how do you know which one you want?

Comment: I don't want to get all text field value . I want particular textfield value . That's why i assign unique tag for each textfield.

Comment: Well if that cell has scrolled off the screen you will be out of luck because the chances are the cell has been reused and now has different value and a different tag.  If you want to get the value of any of the cells text fields you will need to have some kind of data model backing it all up

Comment: I also tried that. I created data model but still after scrolling it wont be able to find first textfield.

Comment: You are never going to be able to find the textfield.  Let me try to explain with an example.  Suppose you have 1000 cells and 10 fit on each screen.  The table view will only keep say 15 cells at a time and then reuse them.  So if you scroll to the end there is no longer a text field with the tag 1 because it has been reused and given a different tag.  The data model is not used to keep track of the text fields it's used to keep track of the values that have been entered.  You need to update the data model each time a text field is changed.

Comment: can you please show me this with example ?

Comment: It depends on how you are getting your data for the table view in the first place.  If you update the question showing that I will try to work on a simple example that shows one way of doing what I mean.

Comment: can you please give me your mail id?  I will mail you sample project.

Comment: If you mean my email I'm sorry I don't give it out at random.  Can you just upload the project to DropBox and share the link or create a git repository or something similar.

Comment: okay , i will share you the link. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is link to my demo project. Please check:   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d3uwh3vtmw10srx/AAALklTNPNLTXuHK8KazAVS7a?dl=0

Comment: Ok I'm about to go and play football and looking at an issue for someone else but I will have a look when I can.

Comment: Had a look and that is just a png file and a swift file.  I can see some of what is going on in it but it doesn't show what you want to do with the textfield values when you tap submit and doesn't have any of the cell information (e.g. what does the SurveyFormTableViewCell look like).  I would need to see more of it and know what you are trying to do with the text field contents when you find it.

Comment: I have added SurveyFormTableViewCell. Please check out the link :    dropbox.com/sh/d3uwh3vtmw10srx/AAALklTNPNLTXuHK8KazAVS7a?dl=‌​0     When user tap submit button, I want to compare textfield values. Suppose if textfield2 value is greater than textfield1 , then only form will be  submitted.Otherwise error is shown.

Comment: Can you not add the entire project?  That would make it much easier for me to look at.  I will see what I can do with the extra information though.

Comment: Right that didn't add any extra information really but in the simplest terms what you need to do is instead of keeping a list of the UITextViews you need to keep a list of the strings that they contain.  Then you need to update that list whenever a UITextView has it's text changed.  My basic example details how to do this kind of thing and someone has marked this question as a duplicate and the other question also has a valid answer so you need to check both those out.

Comment: I can keep list of UITextField strings that user entered but then how will i able to compare those textfields value ?

Comment: Compare them to what?

Comment: Suppose i want to compare fourth row textfield value with third row textfield value or third row value with fifth row value, then how will I achieve this  ?

Comment: If you have stored the entered strings in an array with their index being the position in the array (as you were trying to with the UITextFields themselves) then you can just compare the array elements as normal or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: But my form size might change according to data i recieved from database. So then i wont be able to recognise at which position , whose value is stored.

Comment: Ok well something must uniquely identify each entry in the database so you could use a dictionary and that identifier as the key of the dictionary.  Using a dictionary you won't care about sizes or positions as the unique identifier as key will be used.

Comment: can you please explain me with example?

Comment: Not really without knowing more about your app or more specifically the data model your app is using.  What should I use as the unique ID for my data for example.

Comment: I used combination of srno, pestcode, inspection_no as unique id for my data. Combination of this three  is unique and thats why i used this as id. Value of this three I get from my database.  You can  check it out here: dropbox.com/sh/d3uwh3vtmw10srx/AAALklTNPNLTXuHK8KazAVS7a?dl=‌​0

Comment: Yep that's the same part of the project you have already shared.  I can't run that to test it but I will see what I can do.

Comment: Answer updated with an example of dictionary usage.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now I can keep record of all the textfields value. But now I want to set error on textfield. Suppose I am comparing textfield3 and textfield4 value , if textfield4 value is lower than textfield3 and now i want to set error on textfield4 as "Textfield4 value should be greater than textfield3". then how should I do this ?

Comment: Instead of a single String you can store a tuple of values like this: `var enteredValues: [textfieldId: (String, Error)] = [:]`.  Just change error to whatever you want.  Then you can access them like this: `enteredValues.0 & enteredValues.1`.  You can also give the parameters names if you want.

Comment: But how to set error on textfield in swift ?

Comment: Do you mean visually how or in the data?

Comment: I mean visually

Comment: Well visually there are plenty of things you can do.  You could have a UILabel which you only show if there is an error and put the error message in there or you could change the colour of the text in the text field (e.g. red) to indicate there is a problem (the disadvantage is that won't say what is wrong).  It's all up to how you want to design it.

Comment: But what if  that textfield  scrolled off the screen then how I am able to find out that textfield ?

Comment: You don't.  You record in your dictionary that there is an error with that entry (as I showed earlier) and then when you go to display the cell and the text field check the data and show the error message if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign indexPath.row in cell forsizeitem. Like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SurveyFormTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SurveyFormTableViewCell


    var  pest_code = textfield_id_value[indexPath.row].pest_code
    var srno = textfield_id_value[indexPath.row].srno
    var inspection_no = textfield_id_value[indexPath.row].inspection_no



        cell.text_field.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        cell.text_field.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.text_field.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(tableFieldDidChange(_textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        let id:Int = Int("\(srno)\(pest_code)\(inspection_no)")!
        cell.text_field.tag = indexPath.row


        cell.label?.text =  struc_array[indexPath.item].pest
        cell.label?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.label?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

        return cell
}
```

Comment: My textfield count might increase , so thats why i did't use indexpath.row as tag. And i want to find particular textfield using tag that i set.

Comment: basically when your textfield increase indexPath.row is also increase.

Comment: its work perfectly for 100000000 rows and more

Comment: yes I know that . But  I don't want to get all textfield value. I want to find particular textfield value using tag.

Comment: What you want to achieve ? basically u asked that "Fatal error" this issue is solve? if yes then we move forward and try to solve second issue.

Comment: what is textfield_id_value?its an array?

Comment: if this project is sample, then send me i will check on my xcode and provide a better solution

Comment: yes its an array. Actually id is combination of srno,pest_code, inspection_no

Comment: srno,pest_code, inspection_no? you declare in model and then model treat as an Array?

Comment: okay. can you please give me your mail id ?

Comment: khawar512@gmail.com